# Is there a possibility of a solution in a select option which uses JavaScript and PHP together?

Tags: javascript, php

I have run into a problem between two different coding languages, JavaScript and PHP. Now as you can see from the picture below in the webpage i have a **select list** and  a **add list** .

[image: The menu]

In the select list I am querying the database to get the values out like in the code below shown:

```
<select name="opt_lable" id="select";>

      <?php foreach ($distinctResult as $post) {?>
           <option value="<?php echo $post['label'];?>"><?php echo $post['label'];?></option>
      <?php };?>

</select>
```

Now for the input form that I have `Add list`, I add the value from the database and this value appears into the select option and also when I add the value I am creating a totally new file as shown below in the code:

```
<?php
    include "conn.php";

    if(isset($_POST['AddList'])){

        $addLabelList=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['add_list_for_label']);

        if(empty($addLabelList)){

            header("LOCATION:../admin-panel.php");

        }else{


        $list=fopen("../".$addLabelList.".php","w");
        $OpenExtPhp="<?php \n";
        $CloseExtPhp="?>\n";

        $Header="include 'header.php' ;\n";
        $SidePanel="include 'side-Panel.php' ; \n";
        $PostWindow="include 'post-Window.php';\n";
        $CreatList="include 'create-list.php';\n";
        $Footer="include 'footer.php';\n";

        fwrite($list,$OpenExtPhp);
        fwrite($list,$Header);
        fwrite($list,$SidePanel);
        fwrite($list,$PostWindow);
        fwrite($list,$CreatList);
        fwrite($list,$Footer);
        fwrite($list,$CloseExtPhp);

        $query="INSERT INTO posts(label) VALUES('$addLabelList')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        header("LOCATION:../admin-panel.php");

        }

    }elseif (isset($_POST['CancelList'])) {

        header("LOCATION:../admin-panel.php");

    };
```

the last thing that I do is link the values of the option list to that individual value that I created during submission of the value - as shown in the last code below which is a javascript file :

```
var sel=document.getElementById("select");

sel.onchange=function(value){
    if(this.value=="home"){

        var w=window.location.href="admin-Panel.php";

    }else if(this.value=="Netherlands"){
        window.location.href="Netherlands.php";
    };
}
```

Am I able to link each value that I create with the form `addList` to the page which will be created during that procces of submission? Thnx to anyone who can help me out with this

Comment: I’m having a hard time getting past creating identical files that don’t appear to have dynamic content. It would make much more sense to store content in the database and simply use a template. As it is, I see potential security threats- allowing user input into your file system, and then possibly executing user supplied code. If that’s where you’re heading, it’s a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to send the value of the selected item to the php file that processes the POST data. If that is the case, you have two options

1. You can set a hidden form input (input type="hidden" value="") with the selected item and get the value in the file that processes the POST data
2. You can use $.ajax({}) to post the form data. That would allow you add the select data as POST data to your form